# Upgrading NG-Zorro from V8 to V9 gives: "Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-schematics, ng-zorro-antd

After running `ng update ng-zorro-antd` we get:

```
[error] TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\<user name>\Desktop\Work\<project name>\node_modules\ng-zorro-antd\schematics\ng-update\upgrade-rules\checks\calendar-input-rule.js:4:49)
```

This also happens in a brand new Angular 8 project. The upgrade to Angular 9 works fine but only the NG-Zorro update fails.

These are the contents of the `calendar-input-rule.js` file from the error:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const schematics_1 = require("@angular/cdk/schematics");
class CalendarTemplateRule extends schematics_1.MigrationRule {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.ruleEnabled = this.targetVersion === schematics_1.TargetVersion.V9;
    }
    visitTemplate(template) {
        schematics_1.findInputsOnElementWithTag(template.content, 'nzCard', ['nz-calendar'])
            .forEach(offset => {
            this.failures.push({
                filePath: template.filePath,
                position: template.getCharacterAndLineOfPosition(offset),
                message: `Found deprecated input "nzCard" component. Use "nzFullscreen" to instead please.`
            });
        });
    }
}
exports.CalendarTemplateRule = CalendarTemplateRule;
//# sourceMappingURL=calendar-input-rule.js.map
```

I saw people saying that it might be due to circular dependencies but the app is working fine, so the error might be from the NG-Zorro's imports? Are there any workarounds this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted this issue on [their Github repo](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/issues/5197) and they provided a workaround for it. All we had to do is to install an older version of `@angular/cdk` (even if we don't use it directly) until they release a patch:

```
npm i @angular/cdk@9.2.1 --save
```

We removed `@angular/cdk` from package.json after the update. I don't know if it will affect something in the future. So far so good

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, after deleting node_modules and re-install everything is was gone.

Comment: I did that and I still get the error. Did you get the exact same error for the calendar rule? Also, what was the version of ng-zorro in package.json before re-install? Are you sure you didn't install ng-zorro v9 without running the migration rules?

Comment: The error was the same but not from calendar rule as I remember. Version after upgrade was 9.1.0

Comment: I've made a github issue for this https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/issues/5197